# Confused about the behavior of asterisk in ls command

Tags: bash, shell, ls

On Centos and Debian I tried this.

Does the * with the ls command imply recursive search?

If I start to type a dir name and hit tab I see this:

```
# ls /etc/rc<tab>
rc0.d/    rc1.d/    rc2.d/    rc3.d/    rc4.d/    rc5.d/    rc6.d/    rc.local  rcS.d/
```

I thought if I put an asterisk in the path I would see the same thing but instead it did a recursive search:

```
# ls /etc/rc*
/etc/rc.local

/etc/rc0.d:
K50netconsole  K90network

/etc/rc1.d:
K50netconsole  K90network

/etc/rc2.d:
K50netconsole  S10network

/etc/rc3.d:
K50netconsole  S10network
...
```

The windows dir command would just show me the directories matching /etc/rc* how can I get this behavior from ls (without using the tab key)?

****Edit/Update:

OK so now I understand * is interpreted by bash instead of the command, but is it always interpreted as "enumerate file and folder entries" or if I use it in a different context does it do something else and if so is there like some big if statement in bash that says "if * used with file system paths return file and folder names, if * used with rpm (like **rpm -qa post***) return package names, etc"

Comment: About the last question: try `touch postxpto` followed by `rpm -qa post*`.

Answer (score 8):

Asterisk expands before it gets to the `ls` command, so this is an equivalent of

```
ls /etc/rc0.d    /etc/rc1.d   /etc/rc2.d    /etc/rc3.d    /etc/rc4.d ...
```

which will list contents each directory separately.

You might want to use `ls -d /etc/rc*` to suppress listing the files inside the directories, or use a command that just displays the expansion, such as `echo /etc/rc*`.

Comment: So then * isn't just a wildcard symbol? * is a specific routine in bash that returns the file and directory names of the current (or spcified) directory? Does * run different routines based on context- I'm still a bit confused what * actually means to bash.

Comment: @user1028270 In Windows, the `*` is interpreted by the particular command (`dir`). Here, it is interpreted by the shell (bash), and not the command (`ls`). They mean the same thing, but are applied in different places during execution.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you invoke `ls` with a directory argument it displays the directory's contents. You can alter that behavior with the `-d` option. From `man ls`

```
-d, --directory
       list  directory entries instead of contents, and do not derefer‐
       ence symbolic links
```