# What does the * in this line do/indicate?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm working on a little script and I found another solution like the one I came up with use this line here:

```
for i in *; do
```

What exactly does the `*;` do/mean here? I'm used to seeing `$` variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in *; do
```

The `*` here is the filename globbing character that matches all (non-hidden) names in the current directory.

In each iteration of the loop, the variable `i` will take the value of each of the names matching `*` in turn.

The `;` after the `*` (as in most other places) may be replaced by a newline:

```
for i in *
do
```

Comment: @Saith then you should accept the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Per [Confused about the behavior of asterisk in ls command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/262218/confused-about-the-behavior-of-asterisk-in-ls-command#answer-262221)

> Asterisk expands before it gets to the [...your...] command

So you are passing all the files matching your pattern `*` to `for`